# Non-integer starting_position in regexp_substr PL / SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I have concatenated strings from 3 different columns, like these:

```
salary total 8140 Walter Davis
salary absolute 975004 Nathan Johns
monthly total 11 Emily Grand
```

I want to write out just the names from every row. The problem is, the starting position of the names are not the same, so I can not write a simple number to the starting position parameter in regexp_replace.

So what I want to see is that:

```
Walter Davis
Nathan Johns
Emily Grand
```

My code is:

```
select 
regexp_substr(concat(concat(e.column1, e.column2), e.column3), '\w+',1,'\d+\w')
from exampletable e
```

---

`'\w+'` : With this, I want to write out all the words
`'\d+\w'` : This would be the starting position, in my mind, it means the first word character after the digits, which is the first character of the names.

But I get these error messages:
ORA-12801:
ORA-01722

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not that clear to me. If you already have 3 different columns, why do you need to concatenate them and then separate? Is this an exercise? Also, are you sure you Always have a number before the name? That is, your need could be something like "everything after the number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the part of the string starting after the unique number in the string, this could be a way:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '([0-9])( +)(.*)', 1, 1, 'i', 3)
from (
    select 'salary total 8140 Walter Davis' str from dual union 
    select 'salary absolute 975004 Nathan Johns' from dual union 
    select 'monthly total 11 Emily Grand' from dual union 
    select 'monthly total XXX 11 John Smith' from dual 
)
```

which gives:

```
Emily Grand                                  
John Smith                                   
Nathan Johns                                 
Walter Davis
```

How it works: it splits the string into 3 parts, given by :

- `([0-9])`: a digit
- `( +)`: one or more spaces
- `(.*)`: whatever

The parameter `3` is used to get the substring that matches the third regexp.
This can be rewritten in different ways, I believe this one is clear enough.

Comment: So the 3 parameter is beacuse of the names starts on the third string? Can you tell me a solution if there would be rows where the name starts at the 4th string? And I also have the rows beyond with the names starts at the 3rd place. Thank you

Comment: so if we dont know which one is the name, just that it starts after the numbers

Comment: This is based on the fact that the name starts after the numeric part. the 3 parameter says to get the third part of the string, where the parts are 1: numeric part; 2: one or more spaces; 3: eveything after the numeric part and the space

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
regexp_replace(name,'\D+\d+(\D+)','\1')
```

`\d+` - one or more digit

`\D+` - one or more non-digit

`\1` -  first captured group within `()`

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/939)

Answer (score 0):

Just use *regexp_replace*

( main point of interest is *digits to be included* for purpose of seperating the string ) :

```
 create table exampletable( column_common varchar2(500) );

insert all 
        into exampletable values('salary total 8140 Walter Davis')
        into exampletable values('salary absolute 975004 Nathan Johns')
        into exampletable values('monthly total 11 Emily Grand')
 select * from dual;       

 select regexp_replace(column_common,'^(\D*)(\d*)') "Name"
   from exampletable;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0f92c/2)

Answer (score 0):

Are the names always last, following one or more digits? If so then you can do something like the following:

```
WITH x ( concat_str ) AS (
    SELECT 'salary total 8140 Walter Davis' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'salary absolute 975004 Nathan Johns' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'monthly total 11 Emily Grand' FROM dual
)
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(concat_str, '\D+$'))
  FROM x;
```

Returns:

```
Walter Davis
Nathan Johns
Emily Grand
```

EDIT: Just FYI, there's no reason to use the `CONCAT()` function in Oracle - just use the concatenation operator `||`:

```
concat(concat(e.column1, e.column2), e.column3
```

==>

```
e.column1 || e.column2 || e.column3
```

Hope this helps.